# bootstrap form button is outside of the form div

Tags: reactjs, forms, button, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap and reactJS.

Please consider the following snippet:

```
<Form>
    <!--some stuff-->
    <Button type='submit'>
</Form>
```

the button is rendered outside my form as shown below :

[image: button is outside the form]

How can I bring my button inside of my form please ? I am using `sass` , so I can override bootstrap propreties if needed.

Comment: Why not just wrap everything in a div ?

Comment: already tried, but the button is still outside the div

Comment: Could you provide your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: @MajidM. https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shannon-bbdcn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am not registered on sandbox, so I hope it works to share without saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it with a `FormGroup` and add a `minHeight` to it:

```
<FormGroup style={{ minHeight: "50px" }} className="mb-2">
  <Button className="float-end" type="submit" variant="outline-primary">
    Submit
  </Button>
</FormGroup>
```

[image: Edit hungry-shadow-6lcp9]

Comment: thanks mate, works great, but `minHeight` has to correspond to the Button height to fit well...

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything in a div like so

```html
<FormWrapper class='form-wrapper'>
 <Form>
    <!--some stuff-->
 </Form>
 <Button type='submit'>
</FormWrapper>
```

CSS as so

```
.form-wrapper{
//styles here
}
```